# arcpy label function string formatting

Tags: arcpy, labeling

I have this function works totally fine. But i want to be able to change the font size

```
 def label(wah, field):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        if lyr.name == wah:
            if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
                for lblClass in lyr.labelClasses:
                    lblClass.expression = "["+field+"]"
                    lyr.showLabels = True
```

I have tried something like this but i cannot quite seem to get it to work. The label size is not changing from the code below

```
 lblClass.expression = "<FNT size = '8'>" + "[" + {} + "]" + "</FNT>".format(field)
```

or

```
lblClass.expression = '"{}" + [{}] +  "{}"'.format("<FNT size = '8'>",field,"</FNT>")
```

Just for reference when i am calling the function it looks like this:

```
label("CountyClip", "County")
```

Can someone help me fix my code?

Comment: What about: `"<FNT size = '8'>[{0}]</FNT>".format(field)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a little tied up constructing your string

```
def label(wah, field):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        if lyr.name == wah:
            if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
                for lblClass in lyr.labelClasses:
                    lblClass.expression = "<FNT size='8'>[{}]</FNT>".format(field)
                    lyr.showLabels = True
```

You don't need to concatenate the string together using `+` when you're using the `str.format()`.  Construct your entire string as-is, and use `{}` as the place-holder for input from the `str.format()` such as your field value.

And if you still have trouble with this you could enclose the string in triple quotes `"""` as this can help get around any potential escape character issues.  e.g.

```
lblClass.expression = """<FNT size='8'>[{}]</FNT>""".format(field)
```